# Is it possible to make notebook read-only without using OS file read only setting?

Tags: notebooks, security, notebook-security

I want to make notebook read-only (protect from modification) for all operating systems (when copied from one OS to another OS read-only should remain). Is there any way to do that?

Comment: One possibility would be to save it as a .cdf format.

Comment: Are you wanting to protect against accidental modification or deliberate modification?  Are you worried about someone copying the whole notebook,  posting it into an empty notebook, changing and saving it?

Comment: @mikado I am making my notes for Mathematica in Mathematica notebooks. From time to time I am looking in my notes and I want my notes to be protected against accidental modification when I will look in them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the [`Saveable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Saveable.html) property to `False`.

Use Format -> Option Inspector, set the Scope to Selected Notebook, search for Saveable and set it to False. Then save the notebook using Save As... (since Save is now disallowed).

There is also an `Editable` property. A notebook that is not `Saveable` may still be `Editable`, but the changes cannot be saved. You can prevent all changes with the `Editable` option, but personally I find this inconvenient at the notebook level and only use it at the cell level. For an example of how these options are typically used, look at the documentation page notebooks. These are not `Saveable`.  The notebooks themselves are `Editable`, as input cells can be changed and new input cells can be added. But certain cells, such as headings and descriptions are not `Editable`.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: For anyone who uses it, It is very important to set the Scope to `Selected Notebook`. If you set it to global, than you will not be able to save any notebook.